# history.pushState erases history after refresh if using confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, browser-history, pushstate, html5-history

For some reason, the following code causes the page history to be erased, and I can't figure out why. I have two buttons that simply change the URL with `history.pushState()`. Button 1 sets the query parameter `num` to 1, and button 2 sets it to 2. Additionally, if you navigate back to the page with `num=1`, it will open a confirm dialog, asking if you want to go to `num=2`, which will again use `pushState()`.

If you press button 1, then button 2, you will be able to press back and click ok and be returned to the `num=2` page. You can actually do this as many times as you want. But if you then refresh while on the `num=2` page, you can only press back and ok once. If you press back again, it will "skip" over the `num=1` page and go to the page before it, effectively erasing the history, and leaving the site.

The issue appears to be related to the call to `confirm()`. If I don't use `confirm()`, and instead make my own dialog, it seems to work just fine.

Questions:

1. Why is this? Why does refreshing change the behavior of the back button?
2. How can I make it behave like it does before refreshing, after it is refreshed?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <button onclick="myClick(1)">1</button>
    <button onclick="myClick(2)">2</button>

    <script>
        function myClick(num) {
            const url = location.origin + location.pathname + '?num=' + num
            history.pushState({}, null, url)
        }

        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
            if (location.href.endsWith('1')) {
                if (confirm('Click OK to go to 2')) {
                    const url = location.origin + location.pathname + '?num=' + 2
                    history.pushState({}, null, url)
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```